# Render react native child from async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to render a react native component from an id, which is given to a http request and in turn returns json that the component can use. Since the http request is async, the data that is passed into the PostCard render is undefined. I tried to get around this by awaiting the return of getSinglePost, but data still remains undefined. 
In case it is unclear, the render function calls the renderCard function, which is supposed to wait for json from the getSinglePost function, which then returns a filled PostCard react component.
Any ideas?

```
  async getSinglePost(id: string) {
    try {
      let url = preHTT + apiURL + port + 'post/id';
      url = url + '?postId=' + id;
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      const responseJson: any = await response.json();
      // we should do better error handling gracefully
      if (responseJson['status'] === 'ERROR') {
        throw 'Could not retrieve data';
      }
      // console.log(responseJson['payload']);
      return responseJson['payload'];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async renderCard(id: string, type: string) {
    if (type === 'post') { ***here***
        const data = await this.getSinglePost(id);
        return <PostCard data={data} goToProfile={this.moveToProfileScreen}/>;
    } else {
      return <EventCard goToProfile={this.moveToProfileScreen}/>;
    }
}


        ***render/return stuff above***
        {this.state.markers.map((marker:any)  => (
          <Marker // marker on press function eventually
            key={marker['postid']}
            coordinate={marker['location']}
            image={this.emojiDict[marker['type']]}
            >
            <Callout>
              <View flex>
                {this.renderCard(marker['postId'], marker['contentType'])}
              </View>
            </Callout>
          </Marker>
        ***render/return stuff above***
```

Comment: `render` must not be asynchronous, and you shouldn't do http requests from rendering anyway.

Answer (score 4):

`render` is synchronous and won't wait for asynchronous routines to be completed. In this case the component should be re-rendered on routine completion.

It can be done as follows:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const asyncData = await this.getAsyncData();
      this.setState({ asyncData });
    } catch (err) {
      // handle errors
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.asyncData) {
      // render child component that depends on async data
    } else {
      // initial render
    }
  }
```